# Compare partially-numeric string without casting

Tags: java, compare, comparator, string-comparison

I have googled a bit, but wasn't able to find a solution to this kinda specific problem. I have a `List` of POJOs, which do have a field called `displayCode` (String type). The `displayCode` can have different formats. Some examples:

```
622
622-S
622-1
623 
624
625
625-S
625-1
625-1-S
625-2
625-2-S
```

After sorting they should also be in the order as shown above. With a normal `s1.compareTo(s2);` I get an order like this:

```
1
10
100
101
102
...
```

which obviously doesn't suite what I need. Sadly I have no plan on how I could achieve this in any smooth way (and no other way as well). Also please note, that i can't use anything from Java 8.

Code for testing purposes (you can play around with it):

```
List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "622", "622-S", "622-1", "623", "625",
        "625-S", "625-1", "625-1-S", "625-2", "625-2-S", "6", "60", "666", "1", "2", "3" }));
Collections.sort(s,new Comparator<String>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

        return 0;
    }
});
System.out.println(s);
```

EDIT:
My first thought would go to cast the number till the first `-` to an int and compare that and work my way to the other parts as well. Yet this doesn't sound smooth.

Comment: You might want to focus on what *works* before you worry about *smooth*.

Comment: your only problem seems to be the S at the end, because normal comparison will give you:
1, 2, 3, 6, 60, 622, 622-1, 622-S, 623, 625, 625-1, 625-1-S, 625-2, 625-2-S, 625-S, 666

Comment: Can you show a "bad" sorting for the elements in the array you actually listed above?

Comment: @MárioFernandes: No, because `625-10-S` would come before `625-2-S` (the OP highlighted this issue with varying numbers of digits in numbers in the question, so we can assume more than just the actual quoted numbers in the sample code).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are indeed correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing for it but to isolate the numeric portion of each string, convert to a number, compare those, and only when they're equal do the lexicographic comparison on the strings.

E.g., along these lines (**conceptual**, will likely need tweaking):

```
@Override
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    String[] p1 = o1.split(" ", 2);
    String[] p2 = o2.split(" ", 2);
    try {
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(p1[0]);
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(p2[0]);
        if (n1 != n2) {
            return n1 - n2;
        }
        boolean s1 = p1.length > 1 && p1.equals("S");
        boolean s2 = p2.length > 1 && p2.equals("S");
        if (s1 && !s2) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (!s1 && s2) {
            return 1;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

Comment: sounds like the way i'll have to go then

Comment: Consider the POJO constructor/setter splitting `displayCode` into numeric and string parts to hold as separate fields.  This would simplify the compare method, and if the `List` is large perhaps make the sorting faster.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
Collections.sort(s, new Comparator<String>() {

            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                int returnValue = -1;

                Integer left = returnIfNumeric(o1);
                Integer right = returnIfNumeric(o2);

                // if both values are number
                if (left != null && right != null) {
                    if (left > right)
                        returnValue = 1;
                    else if (left == right)
                        returnValue = 0;
                    else
                        returnValue = -1;
                } 
                // if both values are string
                else if (left == null && left == right) {
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
                // if left is number
                else if (left != null) {
                    returnValue = -1;
                }
                // if left is string
                else {
                    returnValue = 1;
                }

                return returnValue;
            }
        });

    }

    public static Integer returnIfNumeric(String str) {
        Integer number = null;
        try {
            number  = Integer.valueOf(str);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            number = null;
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java strings have a `split` method, which you can use to isolate the numeric part of your POJOs; then you can use `parseInt` to get the POJO as an integer, which would make sorting the way you want easy.